# MySQL deleting multiple columns from two table

Tags: mysql, syntax, join

I have Two tables like this:

```
Table categories:
columns: id, name, parent
1, Foods, 0
2, Drinks, 0
3, FastFood, 1
4, Hamburger, 3

Table documents:
columns: id, name, categoryID
1, CheseBurger, 4
2, shop, 3
```

the parent column has the parent category's id. So When i want to delete Foods entry from categories, i want to delete all child categories and documents.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned before, you could use [FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) to achieve such a task. Below would be your new table structure for MySQL to support automatically deleting both documents and child categories:

```
CREATE TABLE categories (
   id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
   parent INT(11) UNSIGNED,
   INDEX(parent),
   FOREIGN KEY (parent) REFERENCES categories(id) ON DELETE CASCADE       
) engine=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE documents (
   id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
   categoryID INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   INDEX(categoryID),
   FOREIGN KEY (categoryID) REFERENCES categories(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
) engine=InnoDB;
```

Comment: So when i trying to delete how syntax should be?

Comment: INSERT INTO `docs`.`categories` (
`id` ,
`name` ,
`parent`
)
VALUES (
NULL , 'Sample', '0'
)


#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`docs/categories`, CONSTRAINT `categories_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`parent`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) 

I'm getting this error when trying to insert a row from phpMyAdmin

Comment: In this case you are referencing categories.id of 0, which does not exist.  This is causing your foreign key constraint to fail.  You may need to set this value as NULL for parent categories (root level).

Comment: As far as deleting a row goes, you will be performing the usual command: **DELETE FROM categories WHERE id = ?**.  This will trigger the foreign key constraints in both tables.

Comment: Ohh. i figured out. so how should be the syntax to get root level items?

Comment: To get root level items (parent categories), you would use **SELECT id, name FROM categories WHERE parent IS NULL**

Answer (score 0):

I would either use a trigger, or create a more detailed "delete" sproc that would handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Some databases support enforcing referential integrity through foreign keys.  I've done it with Oracle, but I'm no mysql expert.  It's done as an attribute of the foreign key through the keyword 'CASCADE DELETE'.  The database automatically handles it for you.

Here's a quick Oracle example:

```
ALTER TABLE Things ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Things_Stuff
    FOREIGN KEY (ThingID) REFERENCES Stuff (ThingID)
ON DELETE CASCADE
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 choices - in either case I recommend that you create foreign key constraints for your relationships.

Choice 1 is to use [ON DELETE CASCADE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html). I think that this is not a good practice, though, because an unintended delete can have quite surprising consequences.

Choice 2 is to walk the tree and find the records that need to be deleted. You can use a self-join for your categories table to identify all the children in n levels of the hierarchy. This is hte prefered approach, imo.

Other ideas like triggers are just a variation of 2.